# jQuery expanding search icon input, not quite working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this search box that I have done so far but new to JS so a little stuck.

I need it to slide to the right to reveal the input behind it, it did work when I used just button but I guessed I needed to add just the icon so did not submit when you clicked it but slide across, but then I guess also need to make the button show and the icon hide when you enter something in the input and if not when you click icon would just close again.

Something a bit like this I guess.... http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF - which is what I've been trying to base it off.

```js
searchExpand = function(elm){
  var spanIcon = $('.span-icon'),
  searchInput = $('.search-input'),
  searchForm = $('.search-form'),
  btnSearch = $('.btn-search'),
  isOpen = false;

  if(isOpen == false){
    searchForm.addClass('open');
    spanIcon.hide();
    btnSearch.show();
    searchInput.focus();
    isOpen = true;
  } else {
    searchForm.removeClass('open');
    btnSearch.hide();
    spanIcon.show();
    searchInput.focusout();
    isOpen = false;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // lets make the search feature happen!
  $(document).on("click", "span.btn-search", function() {
    searchExpand(this);
  });

});
```

```css
.search-form {
  width: 0%;
}

.search-form input {
  border-right-style: none;
}

.search-form button {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.search-form button i {
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-form span.search-icon {
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-form .form-control {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.search-form .input-group-addon {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

.search-form.open {
  width: 100%;
}

.search-form.open .form-control {
  padding: 30px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form role="search" class="search-form">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Enter a search term" name="search" id="search">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <button class="btn btn-clear btn-search" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"></i></button>
      <span class="span-icon glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is extremely difficult to make sense of what is what you want, and what is not working... could you maybe update your question and be a little more specific? You could divide it into: "what happens is" and "this is what I want", or something around those lines...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your .btn-search isn't inside a span, so your function, searchExpand will not run. when you click the button.

What's in the span is "span-icon glyphicion.... "

If you're using jquery, this would be an effective way of achieving what you want:

Assign an ID to the span call it what you will, and change your js to reflect:

```
 $( "#yourbuttonidname" ).click(function() {
    searchExpand(this);
  });
```

Example of the new span:

```
<span id="yourbuttonidname" class="span-icon glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"></span>
```